Change naming pattern of existing Alembic Scripts
I have an existing set of alembic scripts that use the default naming pattern.
Example:

3cc0ae00e23f_convert_column.py
4b4b8843407e_create_random_table.py
8b6d20ec4d0e_add_new_enum_value.py
...

Alemic works fine and can determine the order in which to execute the scripts; however from the human readability/maintainability it is a pain.  As such it was not until later that I realized I could use a date-based naming pattern in the alembic.ini file; but that would seem to only affect any new alemic scripts created.
Question:
Is it possible to tell alembic to:

Determine the order of the existing scripts
Rename each existing file to use a new Naming Pattern where it replaces the hash with a timestamp string
For any new alembic scripts use the new Naming Pattern

